# R scrape text with rvest, xml, second page of iframe

Tags: r, xml, rvest

Hi I want to extract the page with the Investment Objective from the following link:

http://quote.morningstar.com/etf-filing/Prospectus/2018/1/18/t.aspx?t=SPY&ft=497&d=0833554effb2f4d14d1f23a561738303

I have the following code, but the problem is that it scrapes and gives me the first page whereas i am looking to extract the second page where the actual section and text are

```
linke = 'http://quote.morningstar.com/etf-filing/Prospectus/2018/1/18/t.aspx?t=SPY&ft=497&d=0833554effb2f4d14d1f23a561738303'

read_html(linke) %>% 
html_node("iframe.sec_frame") %>% 
html_attr("src") %>% 
read_html() -> pg

text1<-html_node(pg, xpath=".//div[contains(., 'Investment Objective')]") %>% 
html_text()
```

Comment: The actual content for "Investment Objective" has no specific id or class. You can use this css selector(p:nth-child(22) font) to select it, but it's not generic.